# Is it possible to do fetch and save in Private context,Without notifying anything to main context.?

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm having a doubt about coredata: Is it possible to do fetch and save in Private context,Without notifying anything to main context.?I saw in many example and tutorials that In every save or fetch finally we are end up with main context. Why it is necessary? If i call save on private queue with same persistent coordinator it won't write to Disc? Please clear my doubts before you down vote.

Comment: What problem(s) are you concerned about? What do you think might go wrong that concerns you?

Comment: I want to save coredata using private context but most of the documents i have seen that all save and fetch are passing through main context,ie in parent-child first child save then parent save, Notification method- private context save first then main context save, why is that so? Why thats all end up with main context? why not private context alone capable of saving coredata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different managed object contexts are not automatically aware of changes made by each other. If you fetch the same object in two contexts, change it in one, and save changes, the other context **will not know about the new values** unless you merge the changes somehow. That means it has old, stale data. This is why nearly everyone merges changes, because you want the different contexts to be aware of new changes.

In your case, if you make changes on a private context but do not do anything to merge those changes into a main-queue context, the main queue context will not know about the changes and will still show old values.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is yes, you can do fetch and save on a private context working against the same persistent store coordinator (and persistent store) as the main context. I have it implemented for me. Usually, you want the main context to be aware of the changes by doing a merge of the changes, but that is a not a requirement of coredata. It is up to you based on what what data you are trying to keep in each context.